# Change Registry key via batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

How can I change this registry key in my batch file?

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\CONFIGURATION

Name         Type         Data

Default      REG_SZ         ServerA

That is an example regkey, but the result I am looking for is the same. I would like to change the "ServerA" to "ServerB"

Would this be the correct syntax?

```
reg add "hkey_local_machine\software\configurations" /t REG_SZ /v Default /d ServerB
```

And is there also a way to run this with command priveleges?

Comment: The `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` key is protected from modification by standard users, you must therefore run the script elevated. Please open a Command Prompt window, type `reg add /?` press the `[ENTER]` key, and read the usage information. It should explain each option, and show you why yours is incorrect.

Comment: ```@%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Configurations" /VE /D "ServerB" /F 1>NUL```. In this particular case, as `REG_SZ` is the default, there is no need to include ```/T REG_SZ```  It is always good practice to doublequote key strings, value strings and data strings. It is also safer to include the `/F`orce option, just in case the value already exists, and to prevent a prompt message to overwrite it, in such a case. The `1>NUL` will send any success message to the NUL device, instead of to the default console window.